# while added package in laravel/lumen it gives error of memory limit

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen

I have to read /write/search emails with lumen with use of below command

```
composer require webklex/laravel-imap
```

It gives me arror like below,

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 889192448 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8388608 bytes) in phar://C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 126

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 889192448 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8388608 bytes) in phar://C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 126

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

I have checked my php.ini file for memory limit , It was 2048M ,I have increased it 5000M and also 50000M .but it not worked give me same error.

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.2.*",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "googleads/googleads-php-lib": "^32.1",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0",
        "baopham/dynamodb": "^4.11",
        "laravelista/lumen-vendor-publish": "^2.1",
        "jenssegers/mongodb": "3.2.*" ,
        "php-imap/php-imap": "^3.0"        
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "~0.9"
    },
```

Comment: This will help you https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2704

Comment: You need to increase   memory_limit in php.ini.

Comment: I have increased memory_limit already, that I have mentioned in my question

Comment: Did you edit the correct `php.ini`?

Comment: have you restarted apache2 or what you used?

Comment: but for me it is given error as above, that's why I have increase this limit.after increase limit I have restart apache

Comment: change `memory_limit = 128M` in your php.ini

Comment: ok let me try it

Comment: it gives me this error : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Rule.php on line 76